# Как оптимизировать mysql запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли оптимизировать данный запрос и отыграть секунды времени?

```
SELECT
   e.id,
   e.pid,
   e.tid,
   e.user_id,
   u.user_type,
   Unix_timestamp(e.time) AS time,
   Unix_timestamp(e.time + INTERVAL 0 minute) AS timestamp,
   Unix_timestamp(e.last_reply) AS last_reply,
   e.name,
   u.user_name,
   e.subject,
   e.text,
   IF(e.text = '',
   true,
   false) AS no_text,
   IF(e.time > '',
   true,
   false) AS is_new,
   e.category,
   e.views,
   e.marked,
   e.locked,
   e.sticky,
   e.spam,
   n.user_name AS nick_alias 
FROM
   entries e 
LEFT JOIN
   userdata u 
      ON u.user_id = e.user_id 
LEFT JOIN
   nick_alias n 
      ON n.for_user_id = e.user_id 
      AND n.from_user_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN
   ignore_list i 
      ON i.ignored_id = e.user_id 
      AND i.user_id = 1 
WHERE
   e.tid = 48872 
   AND spam = 0 
   AND i.ignored_id IS NULL 
   OR i.ignored_id = '' 
ORDER BY
   e.time DESC
```

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

```
  CREATE TABLE `entries` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `tid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `uniqid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `last_reply` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `edited` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `edited_by` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `subject` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `category` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `hp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `ip` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
        `tags` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `show_signature` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `email_notification` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `marked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `locked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `sticky` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `views` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `spam` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `spam_check_status` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `edit_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
        INDEX `tid` (`tid`),
        INDEX `category` (`category`),
        INDEX `pid` (`pid`),
        INDEX `sticky` (`sticky`),
        INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
        INDEX `time` (`time`),
        INDEX `tid_time_spam` (`tid`, `time`, `spam`)
    )
```

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод `explain` для вашего запроса: `explain select ...`.

Comment: добавил скрин к основному посту с explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По своему опыту могу дать 3 рекомендации:

1. Попробовать сделать один составной индекс e.tid, e.spam, e.time (добавление в индекс e.time должно по идее исключить filesort).
2. Не относится к оптимизации именно этого запроса, но все же, если архитектура позволяет, то для поля i.ignored_id в таблице стоит запретить NULLы и сделать значение по-умолчанию '', потому что с NULL индексами раньше, как я помню, какие-то проблемы были (если, конечно, такое ограничение уже не сделано).
3. И не забывайте ставить скобки в условиях, т.к. у Вас определенно наблюдается ошибка `WHERE e.tid = 48872 AND spam = 0 AND (i.ignored_id IS NULL OR i.ignored_id = '')`

И еще один момент. В запросе можно написать

```
e.text = '' AS no_text,
e.time > '' AS is_new,
```

Вместо

```
IF(e.text = '', true, false) AS no_text,
IF(e.time > '', true, false) AS is_new,
```

Comment: NULL может появиться не только от значений ignored_id, но с большей вероятностью из-за `left join`'а.

Comment: Да, спасибо за комментарий. Что-то не обратил внимания.

Comment: Да, действительно, многие манипуляции просто существенно сократили время выполнения скриптов. Спасибо! Подскажите, e.text = '' AS no_text, вместо IF(e.text = '', true, false) AS no_text, действительно влияет на скорость, или это сокращение записи? Просто, у меня IF(e.time > '" . $last_page_updated . "', true, false) AS is_new, это получается нужно заменить на e.time > '" . $last_page_updated . "' AS is_new ? И как добавить составной индекс, так? ALTER TABLE `entries`
 ADD INDEX `tid_time_spam` (`tid`, `time`, `spam`);

Comment: По поводу индекса, главное потом проверьте через `Explain`, используется ли он и пропала ли запись `filesort`. Вы правильно написали команду создания индекса, да и по замене условий тоже пример, вроде, верный. По поводу полей `no_text` и `is_new`, никакого хоть каплю заметного роста производительности Вы не увидите, но тем не менее фактически это исключение одного абсолютно лишнего вызова функции, что хоть и на чуть-чуть, но уменьшает использование процессорного времени =)

Answer (score 1):

как видно из вывода `explain`, для всех таблиц используются индексы, кроме таблицы `entries`.

в запросе присутствуют, насколько я вижу, столбцы `user_id` и `time` этой таблицы (которые участвуют в связи или сортировке, но не имеют индексов).

добавление индексов для этих столбцов должно несколько ускорить выполнение *данного* запроса.

Comment: До этого нашел в сети интересную статью на тему индексов, странно, я добавлял индексы для user_id и time, но почему-то тот же результат, при выводе с explain, новые индексы не участвуют. Что я мог сделать не так?

Comment: @aliokero, надо смотреть как вы добавляли индексы. mysql не может использовать все индексы подряд, он выбирает наиболее подходящие. Если бы привели `show create` таблиц, можно было бы что-нибудь сказать. Но для начала необходимо сделать то, что пишет @YuraIvanov

Comment: @ВОРОН, добавил show create таблицы entries к основному сообщению, исправил, как писал YuraIvanov , посмотрите, пожалуйста, правильно ли указаны составные индексы?

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в запросе.

Учитывая приоритет операций (для `or` он ниже чем для `and`), сначала вычисляется предикат для всех `and`'ов, и если он ложен, проверяется `or`. Вот [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/254ac5/2) порядка вычислений (первый и второй запросы эквивалентны, скобки во втором для наглядности).

Из-за `or` условие для `e.tid` не имеет смысла, о чем и говорит план запроса, что индекс по `tid` ничем не поможет, все равно придется смотреть все записи в `entries`, чтоб получить по ним `i.ignored_id`, чтоб проверить его на пустоту.

Должно быть так:

```
where e.tid = 48872 
   AND spam = 0 
   AND (i.ignored_id IS NULL OR i.ignored_id = '')
```

Старайтесь всегда ставить скобки если мешаете операторы. Btw, этот `or` можно заменить на `IFNULL(i.ignored_id,'') = ''`.

Comment: Использовать `IFNULL` для ускорения запроса плохая идея: в запросе `...where ifnull(...)` индекс использоваться не будет. С другой стороны `ignored_id` разве не число? Т.е. зачем сравнивать его с '', если он никогда не будет ему равен?

Comment: @BOPOH ускорение даст правильный фильтр по tid. Если вангую верно, то фильтр по tid должен вернуть несколько записей, а то и вообще одну, время выполнения упадет до миллисекунды. `ifnull` не для ускорения, это просто свертка условия. По поводу `''`, да, логичнее сравнивать с нулем, наверное, какие там значения непонятно...

Comment: про `tid` я не спорю, я просто говорю, что `ifnull` на индексе не стоит использовать (как и любые другие действия), если не знать возможных последствий. Мой комментарий относился только к последнему предложению

Comment: @BOPOH а так по ignored_id индекс и не используется (он не нужен, его нет), поэтому разницы нет никакой, учитывая что фильтруем просто пустые значения ignored_id, полученные от left join при отсутствии соответствующих записей.

Comment: А, не, сейчас используется, ну это потому что запрос неверный... В общем надо сначала запрос поправить, потом уже план смотреть. Тут вы правы.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, все стало намного быстрее грузиться :-)